# What is the use of range() method in KeyValueStore Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I want to understand the use of range method in KeyValueStore state store.

In which scenario we need to use this range method.

In Docs only one line is written.

```
KeyValueIterator<K,V> range(K from,K to)
Get an iterator over a given range of keys. This iterator MUST be closed after use.
```

How far i understand we use state store for some lookup if some record is already present we need to update it or delete it or add it depend on the requirement.

but i didn't understand the use of range method in state store. 
how it's helpful in any situation (any example where this method is helpful)?